# How can I highlight some texts in Servlet (HTML) triggered by some background events?

Tags: html, servlets

I am using Servlet to print HTML tag make it a web page.
If i want to highlight some text inside my web page by some background events.
For example if count > 100,  then highlight some text.
How can I do that? Any example or tutorial?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A servlet generates HTML, and sends it to the browser. Once the response has been sent, the HTML code is in the browser, and there is no way for a background task on the server to modify anything in this HTML code.

You'll need some background JavaScript polling in the page (AJAX), that will ask for updates to the server and modify the HTML page accordingly.

Or you can regularly reload the whole page, but it's less efficient and user-friendly.